# styling a "order by desk" query table

Tags: php, css, sql

I have made a script that is giving me the top 5 players according to most credits trough a desc 0,5 sql query
This is in a table, but it ain't really doing as i what it to go, what it does is every row it gives the table header, and its not making it as 1 table ([see this screenshot](http://static.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/1601/134126/fXOIvOU7.png))

this is my php and css:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `credits` >'0' ORDER BY `credits` DESC LIMIT 0,5");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="floated_elements">

    <table>

    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th> ID </th>
    <th> Wie </th>
    <th> Hoeveel </th>
    <th> email </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['userID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['credits']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>


    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </div> <!-- Closing floated elements -->

    <script>
    $('table tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('th').first().addClass('first');
    $(this).find('th').last().addClass('last');
    $(this).find('td').first().addClass('first');
    $(this).find('td').last().addClass('last');
    });

    $('table tr').first().addClass('row-first');
    $('table tr').last().addClass('row-last');
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

i found that *for* rule and tried to apply it but not really giving the correct results

Edited to give additional code cause asked for

Comment: Where is `for` loop?

Comment: for loop.. something new for me, Imma google it :)

Comment: Will you post full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started `for` loop and put everything into that. Its not a right way. Try as below :

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="floated_elements">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Wie</th>
                    <th>Hoeveel</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `credits` >'0' ORDER BY `credits` DESC LIMIT 0,5");
                $result->execute();
                for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['userID']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['credits']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('th').first().addClass('first');
        $(this).find('th').last().addClass('last');
        $(this).find('td').first().addClass('first');
        $(this).find('td').last().addClass('last');
    });
    $('table tr').first().addClass('row-first');
    $('table tr').last().addClass('row-last');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ty so much! Now the FOR rule is what is causing the table to know how to display?

Comment: it did :) but just for me to learn it, the for rule will tell the table how it should behave?